# Why there is infinite loop? about BigInteger.remainder()

Tags: java, loops, infinite-loop, biginteger

```
public class Ex14_11 {
public static void main(String[] args){
    long b = Long.MAX_VALUE;
    BigInteger a = new BigInteger(Long.toString(b));
    int count = 0;
    BigInteger c = new BigInteger("5");
    BigInteger d = new BigInteger("6");
    BigInteger e = new BigInteger("0");
    while( count < 10 ){
        a.add(BigInteger.ONE);
        if(a.remainder(d) == new BigInteger("0") || a.remainder(c) == new BigInteger("0")){
            System.out.print(a);
            count++;
        }
    }


}
```

}
I need to find the first ten numbers which are bigger than Long.MAX_VALUE. All the numbers should be able to divide 5 or 6 exactly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
a.remainder(d) == new BigInteger("0")
```

You cannot use `==` to compare `BigInteger`s.  Use `a.remainder(d).equals(new BigInteger("0"))` (and similarly for the second comparison).  Note that `a == new Foo(...)` is *always* false in the Java language.

Additionally, you must write

```
a = a.add(BigInteger.ONE);
```

...because what you're writing right now is like

```
a + 1;
```

...which doesn't actually do anything to `a`.

Comment: Could add that `BigInteger.ZERO` is a better alternative to `new BigInteger("0")`.